# Partition by List with query

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

```
ALTER TABLE report_datanew9 PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(host_name) (
   PARTITION pfap VALUES IN (LIKE  '%FAP%' ),
   PARTITION prest VALUES IN ( NOT LIKE  '%FAP%'),    
);
```

Can we use this query inside partitioning? I can't manually add each row to a list as my database has a lot of rows.

Comment: Do you mean `row` or `value` (matching '%FAP%, I guess)?

Comment: I don't know if you can partition on a calculated column. If it's possible, you can create an expression like `case when host_name like '%FAP%' then 1 else 0`, and partition the table on the 0/1 value.

Comment: What benefit do you expect from this PARTITIONing?  I expect you get no benefit, so solving your question is moot.

Comment: I have 133 million rows in my table.. I have around 1000 different hosts and around 200 hostgroups.. So i was making a partition of the hostgroup where all FAP hosts can be added. It would be very beneficial to my data